# How to add data to a RECORD type column using python in bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using python and want to write to a table in bigquery. The schema of the table looks like:

```
test      RECORD    REPEATED    
test.foo  STRING    NULLABLE    
test.bar  STRING    NULLABLE
```

I want to run a command like:

```
table = dataset.table(name='test_table')
table.insert_data(rows_to_insert)
```

What does the input rows_to_insert look like. I keep getting the error:
Repeated value added outside of an array.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your schema was defined as:

```
full_name = SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED')
area_code = SchemaField('area_code', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')
local_number = SchemaField('local_number', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')
rank = SchemaField('rank', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED')
phone = SchemaField('phone', 'RECORD', mode='NULLABLE',
                    fields=[area_code, local_number, rank])
```

Then your data to insert would look like:

```
rows_to_insert = [
        ('Phred Phlyntstone', {'area_code': '800',
                               'local_number': '555-1212',
                               'rank': 1}),
        ('Bharney Rhubble', {'area_code': '877',
                             'local_number': '768-5309',
                             'rank': 2}),
        ('Wylma Phlyntstone', None),
    ]
```

Comment: Copying your example i get
   invalid_argument: Missing required field: full_name.

Comment: Sorry i had trouble loading the schema, I fixed this now and I get the error message: Record leaf types are not supported

Answer (score 1):

I got the `Repeated value added outside of an array` today and couldn't understand why, I seem to have followed the examples quite closely. It turned out that it'd work for a few limited cases, and seem to have something to do with order of keys...

It's a little weird and after poking for a while I figured out that top-level attribute `json` had to be set, so what works is this:

```
table.insert_data([{"json": row} for row in data])
```

And `data` is basically a list of one or more dicts.

Comment: Having said that, I've now realised that I was wrong. I'll update once I have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and trying several options I found out that the correct way to insert nested types in BigQuery with the Python API, using the same example as Dan McClary, is like this:

```
full_name = SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED')
area_code = SchemaField('area_code', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')
local_number = SchemaField('local_number', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')
rank = SchemaField('rank', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED')
phone = SchemaField('phone', 'RECORD', mode='NULLABLE',
                    fields=[area_code, local_number, rank])

rows_to_insert = [
        ('Phred Phlyntstone', [{'area_code': '800',
                               'local_number': '555-1212',
                               'rank': 1}]),
        ('Bharney Rhubble', [{'area_code': '877',
                             'local_number': '768-5309',
                             'rank': 2}])
    ]
```

Notice that the only difference is that you must surround the nested record with `[ ]`